# How to achieve autocomplete suggestions in a cell in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

When I use apple numbers and I start typing text in a cell, the program makes autocomplete suggestions looking up all the other cells in that column.

Now I want to achieve the same thing using google sheets. My best bet was using the data validation function. Yet this results in an error message:

> The selected ranges cannot intersect

Do you happen to know of a workaround or a completely different solution?
Thank you much.